# How to exclude or whitelist particular ip address from iptables

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, iptables, amazon-web-services

I have implemented iptables on my Linux EC2 servers where rate limit incoming for port 80 has been applied. This is my iptables rule - http://pastebin.ca/2307975. I have other EC2 servers that are connecting on this server.

How can I exclude/whitelist a specific ip address from the iptables rule I've set?

Comment: This link gives me a whole idea on how to implement it - http://centoshelp.org/networking/iptables-advanced/

Answer (score 1):

IPTables rules are evaluated on a top-down, first-match basis, so just insert an `-j ACCEPT` rule matching the IP in question above the rule that would otherwise block it and presto, traffic from that IP will be whitelisted.

Comment: @JamesW. - sounds good. It looks like you haven't been accepting answers to your past questions. You really ought to do that - it's part of the give and take on SF (and the rest of the SE network as well).